# Flask View from table of a sqlalchemy-bind doesn't work

Tags: python, mysql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, multiple-databases

I'm using python 3.6.5, flask 1.0.2, flask-admin, flask-sqlalchemy

I have problems showing a View of a table from a second database, sqlalchemy bind configuration, model database, model view all seem like it's ok, but view is not showed in the app, and when I try to force it through the URL, a permissions message appears.

I have checked the bind configuration, when I comment that line, the expected error appears.

I also removed and added some other views from primary database's tables, all of that work well.

I have tried with different ways to make reference to db.session:

```
db.session #like always
db.session(bind=['login'])
db.get_engine(app, 'login')
```

None of that report any error, but view doesn't work.

SQLALCHEMY_BINDS configuration:

```
SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'mysql+pymysql://user:pass@localhost/radius'
SQLALCHEMY_BINDS = {
        'login': 'mysql+pymysql://user:pass@localhost/login_radisp'
}
```

db Model:

```
class Empleado(db.Model):
    __bind_key__ = 'login_radisp'
    __tablename__ = 'empleados'
    id_empleado = Column(INTEGER, primary_key=True)
    nombre = Column(String(255))
    apellido = Column(String(255))
    email = Column(String(255))
```

db Model View

```
class EmpleadoAdmin(sqla.ModelView):
    column_labels = dict(
        nombre = 'Nombre',
        apellido = 'Apellido',
        telefono = 'Teléfono',
        email = 'Email'
```

Creating app builder objects:

```
admin.add_view(EmpleadoAdmin(Empleado, db.session(bind=['login'])))
```

There is not error at all, but view is not showed in the app, when I try to force the view in the URL, next message appears:

```
Forbidden

You don't have the permission to access the requested resource. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a DB access problem, not a flask-admin issue. Check your "SQLALCHEMY_BINDS" access